# Configure S3 bucket to publish events synchronously

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

> I know I can configure an Amazon S3 bucket [to publish events to a SQS topic and to a SNS topic](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ways-to-add-notification-config-to-bucket.html).
>
> But, is it possible to configure the bucket to publish the event to SQS first, and then, when the message has been sent to SQS, have the bucket publish the event to SNS (kind of publish these events synchronously)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Amazon S3 bucket can publish a notification to **one of**:

- Amazon Simple Notification Service (SNS)
- Amazon Simple Queue Service (SQS)
- AWS Lambda

However, SNS can also send a message to SQS. (More accurately, SQS can be added as a subscriber to an SNS topic).

Therefore, you could choose to send the event to SNS, which can on-send the event to an SQS queue. This is a good way to "fork" the event, sending it to multiple SNS subscribers.